# Relation between polynomials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P_{\lambda}(X) = X^4 + 6X^2 + \lambda X -3$ be a polynomial for every $\lambda \in\mathbb{C}$.

Prove that if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of multiplicity $2$ of $P$, then it is a root of $4X^3 + 12X + \lambda$ and $X^4 + 2X^2 + 1$.

My solution: For the first polynomial, it is $P'$. So since $\alpha$ is a root of multiplicity $2$ of $P$, it is a root of $P'$. But what about the second polynomial? I don't seem to find any relation between $X^4 + 2X^2 + 1$ and $P$.

Comment: Eleminate $\lambda$ from the two equations $P=0$ and $P'=0$.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I figured out meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}I&\;\;a^4+6a^2+\lambda a-3=0\\{}\\II&4a^3 +12a+\lambda=0\end{cases}$$

Multiply now  II by $\;-a\;$ and I by $\;4\;$ and add both resulting equations:

$$4I-aII\longrightarrow 4a^2+\lambda a-4=0\implies \lambda=\frac4a(1-a^2)$$

and thus

$$II\rightarrow4a^3+12a+\frac4a(1-a^2)=0\iff a^4+3a^2+1-a^2=0\;\ldots$$